# Is there a way to iterate through the vectors of Gensim's Word2Vec?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to perform a simple task which requires iterations and interactions with specific vectors after loading it into gensim's Word2Vec.

Basically, given a txt file of the form:

```
t1 -0.11307 -0.63909 -0.35103 -0.17906 -0.12349
t2 0.54553 0.18002 -0.21666 -0.090257 -0.13754
t3 0.22159 -0.13781 -0.37934 0.39926 -0.25967
```

where t1 is the name of the vector and what follows are the vectors themselves. I load it in using the function `vecs = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(datapath(f), binary=False)`.

Now, I want to iterate through the vectors I have and make a calculation, take summing up all of the vectors as an example. If this was read in using `with open(f)`, I know I can just use `.split(' ')` on it, but since this is now a KeyedVector object, I'm not sure what to do.

I've looked through the word2vec documentation, as well as used `dir(KeyedVectors)` but I'm still not sure if there is an attribute like `KeyedVectors.vectors` or something that allows me to perform this task.

Any tips/help/advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a list of all words in the `KeyedVectors` object in its `.index_to_key` property. So one way to sum all the vectors would be to retrieve each by name in a list comprehension:

```py
np.sum([vecs[key] for key in vecs.index_to_key], axis=0)
```

But, if all you really wanted to do is sum the vectors – and the keys (word tokens) aren't an important part of your calculation, the set of all the raw word-vectors is available in the `.vectors` property, as a numpy array with one vector per row. So you could also do:

```py
np.sum(vecs.vectors, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The summing vectors was just an example - I really only care about being able to iterate through the vectors. I'll definitely check out the index_to_key, vectors attribute though.